# Xubuntu 12.04 Lenovo T500 hardware mute button will not unmute

Tags: 12.04, sound, xubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa

Have Xubuntu 12.04 installed on Lenovo T500 Thinkpad.  The hardware mute button will not unmute, and I'd like it to work for mute and unmute.

It works to mute, but I have to open a terminal window and run `alsamixer` to unmute headphones and master volume. Xubuntu 12.04 Lenovo T500 hardware mute button will not unmute. The volume control buttons will not unmute, and neither will the PulseAudio volume control.

The http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2195471&highlight=Lenovo+mute suggestion (code, below) did not work.

```
amixer set Master 50%  
sudo alsactl store
echo 'amixer set Master 50%' >> ~/.profile
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with a reboot after
 `amixer -D pulse set Master 1+ unmute`
Problem has not recurred after many days of use.